# Why VS Code terminal do not use the system http_proxy?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I have set http_proxy in Pop OS system settings. (It's based on Ubuntu 20.04)
In normal system terminal, the http_proxy is set correctly.
However in VS Code terminal, the http_proxy is empty.
The Terminal>Integrated:Inherit Env option in VS Code settings is checked.

Comment: What happens when you run `> Terminal: Show Environment Information`? `workbench.action.terminal.showEnvironmentInformation`

Comment: Nothing happens. @soulshined

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure then